# Customizing eclipse code formatting by using predefined template

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

We have a situation, where we need to customize formatting of the code. Regular eclipse built-in format or google format is not helping us.

Actual Format:

```
WS.sendRequest(findTestObject(‘SOAP/Sum’, [(‘variable_0’) : ‘1’, (‘variable_1’) : ‘2’, (‘variable_2’) : ‘3’, (‘variable_3’) : ‘4’
, (‘variable_4’) : ‘5’, (‘variable_5’) : ‘6’, (‘variable_6’) : ‘7’, (‘variable_7’) : ‘8’, (‘variable_8’) : ‘9’
, (‘variable_9’) : ‘10’, (‘variable_10’) : ‘11’, (‘URL’) : GlobalVariable.URL]))
```

Expected Format:
After single quotes and comma, we need a 'NEWLINE' Character. How do we update that?
Note: Unfortunately newline is not coming

```
WS.sendRequest(findTestObject(‘SOAP/Sum’,
[ (‘variable_0’) : ‘1’,
(‘variable_1’) : ‘2’,
(‘variable_2’) : ‘3’,
(‘variable_3’) : ‘4’,
(‘variable_4’) : ‘5’,
(‘variable_5’) : ‘6’,
(‘variable_6’) : ‘7’,
(‘variable_7’) : ‘8’,
(‘variable_8’) : ‘9’,
(‘variable_9’) : ‘10’,
(‘variable_10’) : ‘11’,
(‘URL’) : GlobalVariable.URL,
]))
```

Window --> Preferences --> Formatter--> import the profile xml to fomrat.

Comment: Can you start with what language this is, and why you want to format a complicated argument you're passing in this way instead of declaring it as a local variable?

Comment: @nitind
This is in groovy and specific to a tool named katalon. Where we need this option to beautify our webservice call.

And its a method call, not a variable declaration